# sh: 1: rsync: not found

Tags: python, rsync, systemd

I made a python application and its running fine. So now i made a service still all fine. last part of my program was to sync some files to a different server, rsync command works when i run it as my own users. only when it runs with the server it doesnt work.:

```
import os
..
...
os.system("rsync --remove-source-files -p -e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa' -avq --chmod=a+rwx /source remoteuser@serviceip:/destination/")
```

When I check journalctl I can see this error:

```
 python3[361897]: sh: 1: rsync: not found
```

Here my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Job Server Service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/project
Environment="PATH=/home/myuser/project/projectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/myuser/project/projectenv/bin/python3 /home/myuser/project/job_server.py
User=myuser
Group=myuser
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

First I thought its because the key file ~/.ssh/id_rsa is not accessable by the service but error message indicates it cant find rsync. is this because of the python virtual environment?

When I go into the virtual environment I can run the rsync without any issue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
source projectenv/bin/activate
```

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service definition you set:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/myuser/project/projectenv/bin"
```

This makes the path *only* contain that directory. You probably want something more like:

```
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/myuser/project/projectenv/bin"
```

i.e. something with paths to programs such as `rsync`.

There's no real elegant way of appending to the path. various hacks I've seen would involve changing the execstart line to something like:

```
bash -c "PATH=/home/myuser/project/projectenv/bin:$PATH exec python3 /home/myuser/project/job_server.py"
```

instead of the line setting PATH explicitly.